# Can't connect using SqlManager for Oracle, but Sql+

Tags: oracle-10g

I'm using EMS Sql Manager for Oracle to connect to some Oracle databases but I receive the error

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I just re-setup my PC, due to SSD & RAM upgrades, and I converted my old machine in a VM.

This VM connects successfully and the settings seem to be the same, in fact I copied the `tnsnames.ora` from one client to another (and I use it in Sql Manager).

I can't connect even if I use direct, with connection string, this time it says

```
ORA-06413: Connection not open
```

If I use Sql+, it correctly resolve my TNS identifier and connects correctly to all databases. Same for Oracle Enterprise Manager.

This is a piece of the `tnsnames.ora` I use:

```
CLADB_CLA2014 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (SOURCE_ROUTE = ON)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = CLA2014)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLADB)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After installing 32-bit Oracle client software on a 64-bit Windows
>   operating system (OS) you receive one of the following errors:
>   `ORA-12154` / `ORA-06413`.
>
> **Cause**   64-bit Microsoft OS's install 32-bit applications into   `C:\Program Files (x86)\...` rather than the typical location of
>   `C:\Program Files\...`.
>
> This causes an existing networking bug to occur where the networking
>   layer is unable to parse program locations that contain parenthesis in
>   the path to the executable which is attempting to connect to Oracle.
>
> **Solution**   Find the location of the application that is generating the error.  Check the path to this location and see if it contains any
>   parenthesis.  If so, you must relocate the application to a directory
>   without any parenthesis in the path.

I just moved Sql Manager to 64-bit applications install path (I know it's not super "clean", but nevermind) and now it works correctly.

<sup>Found answer here: [MSDN connecting to oracle on 64bit x64 machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ab662d63-6385-4f73-b27f-d526048f601f/connecting-to-oracle-on-64bit-x64-machine?forum=sqlintegrationservices)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle Enterprise Manager 9.2 on Win7-64bit   I had to 
copy program files (x86)/oracle    to program files,  modify 2 lines of the icon's batch file  C:\Oracle\ora92\bin\oemapp.bat    removing the (x86)

thank goodness, that worked.
same thing to fix toad, I copied the entire quest folder to program files,
and ran it from there.